# Ad is not visible. Not refreshing add. Scheduling ad refresh 60000 miliseconds from now

Tags: android, admob

I am having some CPU usage when my app is backgrounded and the only message I am receiving at Logcat is coming from Adview with the typical:

> "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing add. Scheduling ad refresh 60000 miliseconds from now."

That actually happened to be before, so I added the code to kill the AdView when pausing. Basically my code is already destroying the Adview as follows:

```
public void onPause() {

    if ( adView != null ) {
        adView.pause();
        adView.destroy();
        adView = null;

        Log.i(TAG + ": OnPause", "Pausing the Adview");
    }

    super.onPause();
}
```

Reading all related topics about this issue recommend to do what I've done in onPause, however it is not working. I know the code is passing through this code as the Log is writing at LogCat the message I've introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need `adView.pause();` in `onPause()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

and `adView.resume();` in `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
}
```

**Update:** 
I think is an issue reported to google:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/jz-ZQh86lm0

Comment: The google groups link is what I implemented. Onpause method alone is not working, needs to be destroyed. However I am still having the same issue

Comment: @jorgesys Is it really required to pause and resume adview? I am just worried if we don't do that, does it impact ad impressions ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working . in my mainactivity have method call as below :

```
private void checkAdd() { 
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("8C7A47B9F0F8147BAD75D7DB4C2D026E")  // Will your Test device id.
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mAdView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mAdView!=null){  // Check if Adview is not null in case of fist time load.
    mAdView.resume();}
}
```