# AdMobs testAds are not visible on Galaxy NOTE 8

Tags: android, admob

Here is the serious problem.
I'am using Admobs Banner test adds in my application and they are running or working fine. Although i test my application in other Android Smart phones.
They are visible there too except Samsung galaxy note8 . 
Something with its [specs](https://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-8-specs) or what?
Or Ads are overlapping something i don't get it.
Any help or idea is appreaciated as it is Boss's phone and i need to run the apk on it with working ads before publishing. Thank you

XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-***");
mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

It is working on my phone .
Logcat:

> 10-12 17:13:03.756 20080-25132/indusradio.pk V/FA: Connection attempt
>   already in progress 10-12 17:13:03.757 20080-25132/indusradio.pk D/FA:
>   Connected to remote service 10-12 17:13:03.758
>   20080-25132/indusradio.pk V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
>   10-12 17:13:05.663 20080-20273/indusradio.pk W/libEGL:
>   EGLNativeWindowType 0x747980e010 disconnect failed 10-12 17:13:08.797
>   20080-25132/indusradio.pk V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the
>   service 10-12 17:13:21.083 20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Ad is not
>   visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:13:21.083
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:14:21.143 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:14:21.143
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:14:58.194 20080-20273/indusradio.pk
>   W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7487e90010 disconnect failed 10-12
>   17:14:58.194 20080-20273/indusradio.pk D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   endAllActiveAnimators on 0x747cb33800 (ListView) with handle
>   0x74936b40e0 10-12 17:14:58.207 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   V/ActivityThread: Handle window ActivityRecord{9607a3c
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@1148a44
>   {indusradio.pk/com.example.maham.indusradio.MainActivity}} visibility:
>   false 10-12 17:15:21.163 20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Ad is not
>   visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:15:21.163
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:16:21.174 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:16:21.175
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:17:21.188 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:17:21.189
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:18:21.203 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad. 10-12 17:18:21.204
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000
>   milliseconds from now. 10-12 17:19:21.224 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.

Comment: check Logcat Is there any log related to ads?

Comment: What have you tried? Post code snippets, logs. etc

Comment: @DevMike check update

Comment: @code4rox check logcat

Comment: @Maham see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923688/9868485

Comment: @code4rox can you tell where to add onpause() and onresume();

Comment: @Maham in MainActivity.java